Design review of a USB hub
I'd like to get a peer review on my board design, especially since it's my first board dealing with high speed signals.
The design is supposed to be a high-speed USB hub with 2 ports. These will be connected to 2 UVC camera modules via short cables (5-6 cm). Additionally, there is a small fan control at the top area of the board, that is supposed to activate a 5 V fan at a housing temperature of around 38 °C.
Everything will be integrated into a small case as shown in image 3.



Some further remarks about the design:

The board has 4 layers, the stackup is "signal-groundplane-powerplane(5v)-groundplane".
The differential impedance at 0.3 mm trace width and 0.2 mm spacing was calculated to be ~90.1 Ohms, using Kicad's transmission line calculator.

Some specific questions about my design:

The upstream port is equipped with TVS diodes. Do I need them on the downstream ports too or would this be overkill?
Is the TVS diode near the upstream port (SZESD9101P2T5G) suitable to protect the 5V rail?
The downstream USB traces have length differences of >1mm, the upstream traces are at ~1.3 mm. I could further even that out but this would lead to an uneven distance between some parts of the traces. My guts tell me that, as long as the length difference is within the limits of the USB specification, I should always favor a correct and even impedance. Is that correct?
This question usually leads to opinionated discussions, but I'll try it: Should I put a copper pour on the top signal layer? So far, I've decided against it because I didn't see a compelling reason for it and because I might create problems if the signals excite the pours in one of their resonant frequencies, which causes them to act as noise sources themselves (correct me if I'm talking nonsense here).


The impedance requirement does not depend only on track spacing and width, but the distance between signal layer and ground plane layer too. The impedance depends on stack-up so it can't be verified.
Also the selection of signal-ground-supply-ground is a bit weird, but should work. Usually you route high speed signals on top (and bottom if necessary) and have ground plane under the signal layer. You could run non-essential signals on the bottom instead of using it for ground.

I don't see why an internal link to internal camera needs ESD protection, if the camera is not subject to ESD.

I don't think so. USB VBUS can be higher than 5V. The TVS is rated to 5.0V only, and for high speed data. Such as USB3, HDMI, and DisplayPort. I.e. the multi-gigabit data wires that are nowhere near 5.0V but much lower.

Many sources say 400ps limit is good. That's 8cm. Also if PCB traces are less than 170mm, the 4ns rise time indicates characteristic impedance is not so important. Those are for USB FS though. 150 mils should be good for USB HS, about 3.8mm.

You can choose to pour or not, but the copper planes must be tied to ground so they don't float, and in multiple points so they don't become antennas or resonate with signals. Also the copper pours must be kept far enough from USB lines, such as using 20H or 5W rule. One reason to fill with copper or not is not electrical, but mechanical reasons. In extreme cases there might be different thermal expansions on filled plane and void plane, which may warp the board or cause delamination etc. There is no real answer but a good fab house should be able to tell if the copper is distributed in a way that causes problems or not.



On item 4, beware of coplanar transmission lines. Placing ground on the top layer can reduce the impedance quite a bit, the magnitude of change depending on clearance between ground & signal.

I read up on TVS diodes again and I agree that the working voltage should be higher than 5V. I'll switch to a PESD5V0X1UB,135 diode with max V_rwm of 5.5V, V_br of 5.8V to 10V and V_cl of 8V. The ideal diode would probably break down at 5.3V and clamp to the same voltage. However, such a diode doesn't seem to exist and is likely not manufacturable either. This one is about the best I can do.
